# How to make a hoverfunction in jQuery individually apply to database images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a local database, and, as you can see in my PHP code below, I am taking images from the database and displaying them on my webpage.

In my jQuery script, I tell it to change the CSS features `z-index` and `border color`, and apply a grayscale filter when hovered over the images. (I am going to be adding more effects after I've got my question answered, so please don't suggest to just use CSS instead :) )

However, when I do this, it applies the effects to ALL the images because they all fall under the .singleproject class. Obviously, I only want the effects to show up on the individual image I hover over with my mouse, instead of all the images at the same time. Does anyone know what's the most efficient way to do this using jQuery?

//JS FILE:

```
$(".singleproject").hover(function(){
    $(".textproject").css("z-index", 0);
    $("#projects img").css("border-color", "#34475e");
    $("#projects img").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0)");

}, function(){
    $(".textproject").css("z-index", -1);
    $("#projects img").css("border-color", "#cecece");
    $("#projects img").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(1)");
});
```

---

//PHP FILE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/portfoliotext.js" defer></script>
```

```
require_once("php/connectie.php");


$projectquery="SELECT * FROM projecten ORDER BY projectid DESC LIMIT 15";
$projectresult= mysqli_query($con, $projectquery);

while($projectrow = mysqli_fetch_array($projectresult)){
    echo "<a href='projects/" . $projectrow['projectafbeelding'] 
    . "' rel='lightbox'><div class='singleproject'><img src='projects/" . $projectrow['projectafbeelding'] . "'/>";
    echo "<div class='textproject'><h4>" . $projectrow['projectnaam'] . "</h4>";
    echo "<p>"  . $projectrow['projectbeschrijving'] . "</p>";
    echo "</div></div></a>";
}
```

Comment: You could just use CSS for your hover effects and skip the jQuery.

Comment: Did you consider using CSS? Something like .singleproject:hover { z-index:1; ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly relating to your answer, you need to swap out your class names for 'this' and locate elements in relation.

```
$(".singleproject").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".textproject").css("z-index", 0);        
}, function(){
    $(this).find(".textproject").css("z-index", -1);
}
```

As for the the other elements, I can not see any elements with the id #projects but I assume you want something similar to this.

```
$(this).find('img').css(/* whatever */);
```

However, as a little note you are probably better doing this with CSS and not JS. I will let you look in that :)

Here is a working j[sfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8r9f5nk0/)

Comment: Good answer. Maybe you could extrapolate a bit on what "this" is/does if you have time? It would improve the answer :-)